# Qt 5: open documentation for particular class from command-line

Tags: qt, vim

In Qt 4, I had doc/html folder with documentation, and I used [QtHelp plugin](http://goo.gl/8apZyM) for Vim to immediately open class reference, it is very convenient.

But in Qt 5, I see no html help installed. That is very sad.

I see that we have assistant, it can show local-installed help, but how to make it open reference for given class? Like this:

```
assistant -class QList
```

The only way I found is to use URL:

```
assistant -showUrl qthelp://org.qt-project.qtcore.521/qtcore/qlist.html
```

That works, but it isn't actually convenient: if I know some classname, how can I resolve the URL for it? (the one above for `QList` I've found by hand: just typed `QList` in the assistant's search, and copied URL)

So, the question: for Qt 5, if I know class name like `QList`, `QMainWindow`, etc, how to automatically open the help for it? And, I prefer browser over Qt assistant, at least because Qt assistant doesn't have tabs, so, for each class new copy of assistant will be opened.

Comment: Are you aware that Qt Creator offers a fake vim mode that is already integrated with help, typeahead/completion, and oh, you get an IDE to go with it, too?

Comment: Of course I am, but this fake vim is too fake. (as well as any other vim-emulation mode of other IDEs that I'm aware of)

Comment: OK, I see, you're a vim aficionado :)

Comment: :) well, to be honest, there are **many** things in Vim that I don't like. Vimscript is very ugly, and if someone wants to write plugin for vim, he usually has to write many dirty hacks, to make things work. But yes, power of vim not in just vim itself, but in a lot of plugins around, too. My vim is very customized, and, of course, fake vim can't support vim plugins, so, it's (almost) useless.

Comment: Perhaps the engine that runs vim script can be factored out and made into a creator plugin :)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do in Qt 5. You can feed commands on the stdin to `assistant -enableRemoteControl`.

Say, write `activateKeyword QList` to the stdin, and assistant will display it.

You could do it easily from a separate process. First launch:

```
# for unix socket
nc -lkU ~/.assistantfifo | assistant -enableRemoteControl
# tcp socket
nc -lk 8080| assistant -enableRemoteControl
```

Then, you can do

```
# for unix socket
echo "activateKeyword QObject" | nc -U ~/.assistantfifo
# for tcp socket
echo "activateKeyword QList" | nc localhost 8080
```

The `activateKeyword` selects the index term. If the term is non-unique, like a method present in multiple classes, a selection dialog will open.

To select within that term (e.g. a method in a class), use `setSource #anchor`, where anchor is the method name, or `foo-prop` for a property `foo`.

You have to modify the vim plugin to do something like that.

Almost everything you need to understand this is in `man nc`. nc is short for netcat. Unix domain sockets are named filesystem objects. They are selected with `-U` and recommended over tcp sockets.

The listening netcat creates the socket on the filesystem. Trying to write to a non-existent socket is a no-op, so `nc -U ~/.assistantfifo` is a harmless no-op if `~/.assistantfifo` doesn't exist.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to mention that `assistant` has bugs: when it is started with `-enableRemoteControl`, it significantly loads CPU for 10-30 seconds, but even more, sometimes it gets completely frozen and almost crashes my X (at Linux Mint 13 LTS), so that I have to reboot (killing assistant doesn't help). Filed a bugreport: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-38104

Comment: @DmitryFrank Are you sure that the `-enableRemoteControl` has an effect here? I see this behavior on all platforms, when started without any parameters. clucene is a hog. It seems that Qt Creator either doesn't use it, or uses it in a way that doesn't bog things down. There's no such thing as "almost crashing X". Either you crash, or you don't. Just because it's unresponsive doesn't mean that it's crashed. You may be low on memory.